# How to fix following error when using Camera and Android Image Cropper library

Tags: android, image, camera

How to fix following error when using Camera and Android Image Cropper library:

After take a photo, it reopens the camera and the crop image.

This will open twice for the camera. Can anyone say where is the problem?
I Cannot resolve this error. 
pleas help me.

Config:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 28
```

dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

My `Permission` and `camera` code:

```js
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
else
{                                                  
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"file"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"));
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NewAdActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);
camera_intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(camera_intent,1);
}
```

and `onActivityResult`:

```js
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
if (requestCode==1&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)       //camera
{
CropImage.activity(uri).setAspectRatio(1,1).setRequestedSize(512,512).start(this);
}
else  if (requestCode==2&&resultCode==RESULT_OK) {     //gallery
uri=data.getData();
CropImage.activity(uri).setAspectRatio(1,1).setRequestedSize(512,512).start(this);
}

else if (requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
{
CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
 Uri resutlUri=result.getUri();
images.get(current_image).setImageURI(resutlUri);
fill_images[current_image]=true;
BitmapDrawable bd=((BitmapDrawable) images.get(current_image).getDrawable());
Bitmap bm=bd.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bao=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,bao);
image_base64=Base64.encodeToString(bao.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
checkConnection();
new upload_image().execute();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I guess problem is that the CropImage activity is started after the CameraActivity has returned some result. This is why camera is being opened twice. You can try something like this:

```
CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start((Activity) view.getContext());
```

After that I got the image as Bitmap by overriding `onActivityResult()` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            Bitmap bmp = null; 

                try {
                    InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(result.getUri());
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), ex.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(context, errorConvert, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end your bmp variable will contain the Bitmap image and you can process it as required.

It worked for me, hope it works for you too and good luck!